# Add a column to pandas dataframe containing the proportions for a particular column, based on grouping column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some data for which I want to do the following:

- group by a set of columns G
- for each grouping find the proportion of a particular column within the group
- return the full data with the additional proportion column

I'm not sure what a decent approach to this is though, this is something that I tried:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": [1, 2, 3, 4] + [4, 5, 6, 7],
        "y": ["a"] * 4 + ["b"] * 4,
    }
)
```

gives

```
   x  y
0  1  a
1  2  a
2  3  a
3  4  a
4  4  b
5  5  b
6  6  b
7  7  b
```

then

```py
pd.concat(
    [
        data,
        data.groupby("y")
        .apply(lambda df: df["x"].div(df["x"].sum()))
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={"x": "proportion"})
        .drop(["y", "level_1"], axis=1),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

gives

```
   x  y  proportion
0  1  a    0.100000
1  2  a    0.200000
2  3  a    0.300000
3  4  a    0.400000
4  4  b    0.181818
5  5  b    0.227273
6  6  b    0.272727
7  7  b    0.318182
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it more easily with:

```py
data["proportion"] = data["x"] / data.groupby("y")["x"].transform("sum")
print(data.to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | x | y | proportion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a | 0.1 |
| 1 | 2 | a | 0.2 |
| 2 | 3 | a | 0.3 |
| 3 | 4 | a | 0.4 |
| 4 | 4 | b | 0.181818 |
| 5 | 5 | b | 0.227273 |
| 6 | 6 | b | 0.272727 |
| 7 | 7 | b | 0.318182 |